# Setting the height of a div to 100% does not fill the entire height of the container div

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to vertically center the navigation bar in the header of my website. While doing that, I needed to set the height of the div with the id "navigation-bar-container" to 100%. However, that does not seem to fill the entire height of the parent div with the id "header".

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Danny Watts</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro&display=swap" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header">
                <h1 id="title">Danny Watts</h1>
                <div id="navigation-bar-container">
                    <div id="navigation-bar">
                        <a href="/" class="navigation-bar-link">Homepage</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="body">
                <p>Welcome to my website!</p>
                <p>The font used is <a href="https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Source+Sans+Pro">Source Sans Pro</a>.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                <p>&copy; 2020 Danny Watts</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**stylesheet.css**

```
body {
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
}

body, a, p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin: 0px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#header {
    background-image: url("header-background-picture.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

#title, .navigation-bar-link {
    float: left;
}

#header, #body, #footer {
    padding: 25px;
}

#footer {
    background-color: rgb(225, 225, 225);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

#navigation-bar-container {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
}

#navigation-bar {
    margin: auto;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct by adding `height: 100%` to `#navigation-bar-container` but that only works if it's parent element in this case the `#header` has a fixed height in this case I have set it to `60px`.

I have changed the color of the `header` and the `nav-bar-container` so you can better see this below.

```css
body {
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
}

body, a, p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin: 0px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#header {
    background-image: url("header-background-picture.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: green;
    background-position: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

#title, .navigation-bar-link {
    float: left;
}

#header, #body, #footer {
    padding: 25px;
}

#footer {
    background-color: rgb(225, 225, 225);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

#navigation-bar-container {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#navigation-bar {
    margin: auto;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Danny Watts</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro&display=swap" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header">
                <h1 id="title">Danny Watts</h1>
                <div id="navigation-bar-container">
                    <div id="navigation-bar">
                        <a href="/" class="navigation-bar-link">Homepage</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="body">
                <p>Welcome to my website!</p>
                <p>The font used is <a href="https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Source+Sans+Pro">Source Sans Pro</a>.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                <p>&copy; 2020 Danny Watts</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```